# How to prove that the improper integral $\int_0^\infty \sin(x^3)\, dx$ converges?

Tags: calculus

How to prove that the improper integral $$\int_0^{\infty} \sin(x^3)\, dx$$ converges?

I wanted to use the Taylor series for $\sin(x)$ , and with that I get $\lim \sum \frac{(-1)^n a^{6n+4}}{(2n+1)!(6n+4)} $ as $a$ converges to infinity, but I don't know what to do afterwards. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you wanted to say, $\int_{0}^{\infty} \sin(x^{3})dx$

Comment: Yes i forgot to write dx. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Have you ever heard of Fresnel integral?

Comment: Actually no. I'm a calc 1 student.

Comment: It's difficult to do without complex Analysis. But the best way which might help you to solve the integral will be to watch [this](https://youtu.be/VF7ud3Al6d8) video.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does $\int_{0}^{\infty} \sin(x^3) \, dx$ converge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4367294/does-int-0-infty-sinx3-dx-converge)

Comment: @RamanujanXV that link does not have a complete answer. [The generalized question does](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2275730/integrals-of-the-form-int-0-infty-sin-gx-dx?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: You can show convergence by associating the integral to an Alternating series.

Answer (score 1):

Consider
$$
T(A) := \int_0^A \sin(x^3)\;dx .
$$
We want to show this converges as $A \to \infty$.
Change variables $y=x^3$,
$$
T(A) = \int_0^{A^3} \frac{\sin(y)}{3y^{2/3}}\;dy .
$$
So $T(A) = T_1+T_2(A)$, where
$$
T_1 = \int_0^1 \frac{\sin(y)}{3y^{2/3}}\;dy
\\
T_2(A) = \int_1^{A^3} \frac{\sin(y)}{3y^{2/3}}\;dy
$$
Now for $T_1$, note
$$
\left|\frac{\sin(y)}{3y^{2/3}}\right| \le 
\frac{1}{3y^{2/3}}
$$
and
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{dy}{3y^{2/3}} = 1
$$
so $T_1$ conveges.
Next for $T_2$, integrate by parts
\begin{align}
T_2(A) &= \int_1^{A^3} \frac{\sin(y)}{3y^{2/3}}\;dy
= \left.-\frac{\cos(y)}{3y^{2/3}}\right|_{y=1}^{y=A^3} - 
\frac{2}{9}\int_1^{A^3}\frac{\cos(y)}{y^{5/3}}\;dy
\\&
= \frac{-\cos(A^3)}{3A^2} +\frac{\cos(1)}{3}
-\frac{2}{9}\int_1^{A^3}\frac{\cos(y)}{y^{5/3}}\;dy
\end{align}
Note that
$$
\lim_{A \to\infty} \frac{-\cos(A^3)}{3A^2} = 0 .
$$
Also,
$$
\left|\frac{\cos(y)}{y^{5/3}}\right| \le \frac{1}{y^{5/3}}
$$
and
$$
\int_1^\infty \frac{dy}{y^{5/3}} = \frac53
$$
Thus $\lim_{A\to\infty}T_2(A)$ exists.

Answer (score 0):

If you have seen the video link I mentioned then,
Set $a=0,b=1,n=3,s=\frac{1}{3}$
Then it will follow that,
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(x^{3})dx = \frac{\Gamma(1/3)}{6}$$

Comment: I did(and thanm you for that) but my prof informed me that i can't use gamma function. Any other ideas?

Comment: What your professor said is not a surprise.  The problem is: show the integral converges.  That is easier to do than: evaluate the integral.

Comment: Well, I happened to see [this](https://youtu.be/iCwiDPL3EMI) video which derives the Fresnel integral in awesome way. You can do that for your power cubed case too. Btw, I agree with @GEdgar.

Comment: Well that's exactly what i want to do. I dont want to evaluate the integral itself. How do i prove that it converges? I did some stuff, do you happen to have discord so that we could talk about it? If you have time. @GEdgar